# How to accept user input in a class when using private variables?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have created a class called `User`:

1. has 4 private variables
2. a `get_input()` and `print_output()` function
3. a `main` function where I am accepting user input, where I have to initialize a new set of variables to pass the user input to the `get_input()` function

My question is: Do I have to define a new set of variables? Or is there any way to `name`, `DOB`, etc. directly to the `get_input()` function?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class User
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string DOB;
    std::string telephone_no;
    std::string add;

public:
    int main();

    User()
    {
        name  = "";
        DOB = "";
        telephone_no = "";
        add = "";
    }

    void get_input(std::string &name , std::string &DOB , std::string &telephone_no , std::string &add)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->DOB = DOB;
        this->telephone_no;
        this->add = add;
    }

    void print_output()
    {
        std::cout << name;
        std::cout << DOB;
        std::cout << telephone_no;
        std::cout << add;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::string  DOB;
    std::string telephone_no;
    std::string add;
    std::vector<std::string> ;
    User obj ;
    std::cout << "Enter the name of the user : ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Enter the date of birth of the user : ";
    std::cin >> DOB;
    std::cout << "Enter the telephone number of the user : ";
    std::cin >> telephone_no;
    std::cout << "Enter the address of the user : ";
    std::cin >> add;
    obj.get_input(name , DOB , telephone_no , add);
    obj.print_output();
 }
```

Comment: You should input the variables first, then pass them to the class's constructor, when creating an instance of the class, which will use them to construct its private members.

Comment: Member function can access all member variables. The purpose of making member variables `private` is to limit their access to member functions of the own class.

Comment: On another note, why do you declare the `main` function in the `User` class? The `main` function where execution starts is a non-member function in the global namespace scope, technically it's `::main`. You declare (but do not define) `::User::main` which s a totally different function.

Comment: OT: Assigning empty string literals to default-initialized `string` objects in constructor is totally useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed the advice of Sam Varshachik

and changed my program accordingly:

You should input the variables first, then pass them to the class's constructor, when creating an instance of the class, which will use them to construct its private members

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
class User
{
private :
std::string name;
std::string  DOB;
std::string telephone_no;
std::string add;



public :



User(std::string &name , std::string &DOB , std::string &telephone_no , std::string &add)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->DOB = DOB;
    this->telephone_no;
    this->add = add;
}



void print_output()
{
    std::cout << name;
    std::cout << DOB;
    std::cout << telephone_no;
    std::cout << add;
    


}

};




int main()
{
//initializing local variables

std::string name;
std::string  DOB;
std::string telephone_no;
std::string add;
std::vector<std::string> v;



//prompting the user to get essential details
std::cout << "Enter the name of the user : ";
std::cin >> name;
std::cout << "Enter the date of birth of the user : ";
std::cin >> DOB;
std::cout << "Enter the telephone number of the user : ";
std::cin >> telephone_no;
std::cout << "Enter the address of the user : ";
std::cin >> add;

//passing the entered_input into the object variables
User obj(name , DOB , telephone_no , add);
obj.print_output();
```

}